# Kubernetes pod crashing with CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

When I run the logs I see an entry:

```
2018/11/05 20:12:09 [emerg] 1#1: socket() [::]:8443 failed (97: Address family not supported by protocol)
```

Not sure if this is an IPv6 issue or a firewall issue?

This is for IBM API Connect on Kubernetes.

Comment: What pod is this one? kube-apiserver?  What version of K8s?

Comment: this is ipv6 issue

Comment: Version 1.11 and on the pods running the ibm api connect ui server.  How to configure the pods to support ipv6

Answer (score 0):

IPv6 does not fully implemented yet. Take a look at this [discussion](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/508).  It is still in progress.